# How to show timezone abbreviation with the date

Tags: ios, objective-c, timezone, nsdateformatter, nstimezone

I am getting a time in UTC and want to append timezone abbreviation with it. I have the below code to get the timezone abbreviation but it is giving as GMT +5.30. I want as IST.

For America it is giving as EDT, I need for all the timezones to give 3 letter abbreviation.

Is that possible?

Please check the below code:

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
NSDate* sourceDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2015-03-16T13:08:17.989Z"];
NSTimeZone* destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
NSString *str =[destinationTimeZone abbreviation];

NSDateFormatter* dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd yyyy, HH:mm "];
NSString* localTime = [dateFormat stringFromDate:sourceDate];
NSString* str1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",localTime, str];
NSLog(@"localTime:%@", str1);
```

The output is:

```
localTime:March 16 2015, 18:38 , GMT+5:30
```

I need it as

```
localTime:March 16 2015, 18:38 , IST
```

Please help!

Comment: I did the same. Please check the code

Comment: [IST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel_Standard_Time), [IST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Standard_Time), or [IST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Ireland)?

Comment: IST for Indian Standard Time.

Comment: But is IST the only time zone that is GMT+5:30?

Comment: Yes, but there can be GMT+ or GMT - for other timezones. I am looking for a generic way to show a 3 letter keyword like PST, EDT, IST belonging to their timezones.

Comment: Look through [this list](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/) and you'll see that multiple time zone abbreviations share the same offset from GMT.  Therefore how is a system supposed to know which one you want in cases where more than one is available?

Comment: *"I need for all the timezones to give 3 letter abbreviation."* Except not all time zones have a three letter abbreviation.

Answer (score 4):

You can set time zone to your date like :

```
[dateFormat setTimeZone:DesiredTimeZone];
```

Then format it using date formatter :

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
formatter.dateFormat = @"dd MMM @ HH:mm z";
```

Abow Code into `z`  property according Time Zone in 03 letter Format.

For More details [click here](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Answer (score 0):

IST is actually an ambiguous abbreviation. 
There is [Israel Standard Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel_Standard_Time), [Indian Standard Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Standard_Time) and [Irish Standard Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Ireland). All of them are abbreviated IST.

Though some of the abbreviations can be used to create a valid NSTimeZone object (iOS basically guesses which timezone you want), NSTimeZone won't return an abbreviation that stands for more than one timezone.

If you insist on using `"IST"` you can create it yourself. Just compare `secondsFromGMT`:

```
NSTimeZone *timezone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"IST"];
NSString *abbreviation = [timezone abbreviation];
if (![[NSTimeZone abbreviationDictionary] objectForKey:abbreviation]) {
    NSLog(@"\"%@\" is not a real abbreviation", abbreviation);
    if (timezone.secondsFromGMT == 19800) {
        abbreviation = @"IST";
    }
}
NSLog(@"Abbreviation: %@", abbreviation);
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time zone has a name of the form *area/city* (a few have three parts), for example *Europe/London* and *Asia/Kolkata*. All of these *may* have an abbreviation, or two if daylight savings is observed, and different zones with the same GMT offset may have different abbreviations (and zones with different offsets may use the same abbreviation - abbreviations are *not* unique).

You can discover the zones Cocoa knows about with the following fragment:

```
for(NSString *zone in [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames])
{
   NSTimeZone *tz = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:zone];
   NSLog(@"%@: %@", zone, tz.abbreviation);
}
```

This will output a list of names and the *current* abbreviation, if known, or GMT offset, if the abbreviation is not known. The abbreviation is *current* as it takes account of daylight savings.

If this code shows an abbreviation starting with GMT+ or GMT-, as it will for Asia/Kolkata, you could use your own table to lookup the abbreviation. E.g. create an `NSDictionary` which maps time zone names to an array or dictionary containing one or two abbreviations, for standard and daylight savings time. You could store this table as a plist and load it in your application.

Given any `NSDate` and `NSTimeZone` use `abbreviationForDate:` to determine if OS X knows the abbreviation; if it does not use `name` and `isDaylightSavingsForDate:` to index into your own table.

For a list of zones and abbreviations just Google.

**OR**

If you are happy with C-level interactions you can decode the files stored in `/usr/local/zoneinfo`, for example `/usr/local/zoneinfo/Asia/Kolkata` i.e. the path formed from the directory followed by the zone name. These are binary files and the format is described in the Unix man page `tzfile(5)`. The file for Kolkata contains the IST abbreviation (as does the one for Dublin).

HTH

Comment: It's also possible to get the text files used to create the zoneinfo files, from IANA: http://www.iana.org/time-zones

Answer (score 0):

You can get the time zone abbreviation when you have the timezone name using this.

```
+ (NSString *)getAbbriviationByTimeZone:(NSString *)timeZone {
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"America/Halifax"])
        return @"ADT";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"America/Juneau"])
        return @"AKDT";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"])
        return @"ART";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"America/Halifax"])
        return @"AST";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"Asia/Dhaka"])
        return @"BDT";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"America/Sao_Paulo"])
        return @"BRST";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"America/Sao_Paulo"])
        return @"BRT";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"Europe/London"])
        return @"BST";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"Africa/Harare"])
        return @"CAT";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"America/Chicago"])
        return @"CDT";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"Europe/Paris"])
        return @"CEST";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"Europe/Paris"])
        return @"CET";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"America/Santiago"])
        return @"CLST";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"America/Santiago"])
        return @"CLT";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"America/Bogota"])
        return @"COT";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"America/Chicago"])
        return @"CST";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"Africa/Addis_Ababa"])
        return @"EAT";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"America/New_York"])
        return @"EDT";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"Europe/Istanbul"])
        return @"EEST";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"Europe/Istanbul"])
        return @"EET";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"America/New_York"])
        return @"EST";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"Asia/Dubai"])
        return @"GST";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"Asia/Hong_Kong"])
        return @"HKT";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"Pacific/Honolulu"])
        return @"HST";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"Asia/Bangkok"])
        return @"ICT";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"Asia/Tehran"])
        return @"IRST";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"Asia/Calcutta"])
        return @"IST";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"Asia/Tokyo"])
        return @"JST";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"Asia/Seoul"])
        return @"KST";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"Asia/Hong_Kong"])
        return @"HKT";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"Europe/Moscow"])
        return @"MSD";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"Europe/Moscow"])
        return @"MSK";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"America/Denver"])
        return @"MST";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"Pacific/Auckland"])
        return @"NZDT";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"Pacific/Auckland"])
        return @"NZST";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"America/Los_Angeles"])
        return @"PDT";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"America/Lima"])
        return @"PET";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"Asia/Manila"])
        return @"PHT";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"Asia/Karachi"])
        return @"PKT";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"America/Los_Angeles"])
        return @"PST";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"Asia/Singapore"])
        return @"SGT";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"Africa/Lagos"])
        return @"WAT";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"Europe/Lisbon"])
        return @"WEST";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"Europe/Lisbon"])
        return @"WET";
    if ([timeZone isEqualToString:@"Asia/Jakarta"])
        return @"WIT";
    return nil;
}
```